# How to add a panel on index page in ActiveAdmin when index section has no result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm using the ruby gem ActiveAdmin.  On the `index` page, I want to show a few panels in addition to the index listing of records.

I have code like the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register City do
    belongs_to :country

    index do
        column :name
        column :population
        column :elevation

        panel 'Languages in Country' do
            ul do
                country.languages.each do |language|
                    li language
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The idea is when I go to `http://localhost:8000/admin/countries/3/cities`, I'll show a list of cities of the country, and below this table, I'll show the country's languages in a separate `panel`.

The problem I'm having is that when a country has *no* cities, the language panel is also *NOT* shown (even though it has languages).

How do I show the language panel when a country has no city data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Subclass and override [ActiveAdmin::Views::IndexList](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/c301ab126b3fac1962edeac124eb46e885217420/lib/active_admin/views/components/index_list.rb#L24), something like:

```
class IndexListWithCountryPanel < ActiveAdmin::Views::IndexList
  def build(index_classes)
    if current_filter_search_empty?
      panel 'Languages in Country' do ... end
    else
      index_classes.each do |index_class|
        build_index_list(index_class)
      end
    end
  end
```

Register the [customized index page](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html) with:

```
index as: IndexListWithCountryPanel do
  ... # as before
end
```

It would be more DRY to always display the panel in IndexListWithCountryPanel and not the index block. Have you considered adding the country languages to the sidebar instead? Disclaimer: this is based on my reading of the code and docs, I have not done this myself.